# Are we no longer getting top bar notifications when earning a privilege?

Tags: discussion, notifications, privileges

Before when I was achieving privilage it was showing me orange colour popup on top saying congratulations! you have gained privilages for So and so.

Now it is not appearing. Has it been removed recently?

Comment: See this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84225/orange-bar-not-appearing-when-a-new-privilege-is-earned

Comment: @Shadow, looks like that is the correct answer, please post it, his reputation is around 200 on SO, so its the ads, and that would not be notified according to waffles's list

Comment: Right now i missed reduce ads privilage. But before this I missed vote down and create chat rooms privilage notification also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the table [posted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84225/orange-bar-not-appearing-when-a-new-privilege-is-earned/84317#84317), the "reduced advertisement" privilege gained at 200 reputation does not invoke any notification.

Soon when you reach 250 rep at SO you should get notification for "View close votes", unless you associate the accounts.

Comment: sorry for late reply but i missed previous 2 notifications also.

Comment: @Harshad so this means your account is "Veteran" as you associated your SO account with your Meta account. I fear this can't be undone, so you'll get notification only at 2000 rep for "Edit questions and answers". You can try and email team@stackoverflow.com asking to dis-associate your accounts if it's really important to you..

Comment: hmm "Veteran".. dont knw how it happend.Its not much of really importance now but just was wondering.2000 is long way to go. Thanks anyways.. :)

Comment: @Harshad well, it's your [lucky day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3735/how-to-dissociate-associated-accounts) :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can get it anytime with

```
javascript:StackExchange.notify.show("You have gained the superpower!","1")
```

Comment: This script is cool n intersting. Thanks for that. But it motivates more when it comes automatically after achieving it.. :D (BTW I got that message but i am not able to close it)

Comment: @Harshad, heh, forgot to pass dummy id :P updated

Comment: @YOU.. hey. Still not working.

Comment: @Harshad, strange, works on my FF4, and Chrome 12, what browser are you using?

Comment: @YOU. I tried it on IE8 and Firefox

Comment: Harshad, Imm, I couldn't figured out why ....

Comment: @YOU.. Yup.. that do get close in Google chrome.. :)