# When you hit 100 Reputation on StackOverflow, it only shows "edit community wiki"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Basically, where it should show something like " you've earned edit community wiki and one more privilege " it shows only that I've earned edit community wiki.  When in fact I have earned the ability to create rooms as well (100% in permissions menu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86951/are-we-no-longer-getting-top-bar-notifications-when-earning-a-privilege/86955#86955) and [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84225/orange-bar-not-appearing-when-a-new-privilege-is-earned/84317#84317).

Maybe as you associated your SO account with your Meta account today you're considered Veteran, but in such case you shouldn't have got any notification unless that table posted by waffles has changed.

Comment: I obtained both permissions upon hitting 100 Reputation, I am simply reporting a bug where the message did not show that I gained both.

Comment: @cbr I know that's why I didn't vote to close your question as duplicate just posted links as reference to similar problems.

Comment: I see, alright.  Thank you.  I'll also note that while I am a "veteran" by that description, I have gotten a notification for every badge and permission so far, which that table does not say is right.

Comment: @cbr you're veteran only from the moment you associated your account.. :)